# Strings to textbox to graphics to ImageCollage

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation

I have a set of 42 open comments which will increase in the near future. They all have quite a different length, form 25 to 1294 characters atm, 300 in the mean.

I used a weird combination of (minimal example)

```
text=StringRiffle@RandomWord["CommonWords", 15]    
Panel[TextCell[StringJoin[text], "Text",   Hyphenation -> True], ImageSize -> 300]
```

to get nice rectangled text-boxes. I am quite sure there is a better solution and I am looking forward to ideas. Then  I wanted to use GraphicsGrid[] to convert those single boxes to graphics in order to use ImageCollage. However, GraphicsGrid[] is either to small (cuts of) or to large (empty space)

Any other ideas my fellow #graphicsdesignwithmathematica users? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does something like `Rasterize[TextCell[text, Hyphenation -> True], ImageFormattingWidth -> 200]` which works perefectly with `GraphicsGrid` helps ?

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks for your input!
`text = StringRiffle@RandomWord["CommonWords", 150];
Rasterize[TextCell[text, Hyphenation -> True],
 ImageFormattingWidth -> 200]
GraphicsGrid[{{%}}]`
does not work for me!

Comment: Your code runs on 13.1 but adds additional padding. If you want to remove them, use can use `GraphicsGrid[ ... , AspectRatio -> All]`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is useful, but the following packs 30 texts of different sizes into 4 columns.  Some calculations done to make the columns not too different in size.

```
text = Table[
   ResourceFunction["RandomText"][RandomChoice[Range[6, 80]]], 30];
p = Panel[TextCell[#, "Text", Hyphenation -> True], 
     ImageSize -> 300] & /@ text;
id = ImageDimensions[Rasterize@#][[2]] & /@ p;
totId = Total[id];
acc = Accumulate[id];
nc = 4;
stops = #*totId/nc & /@ Range[nc];
near = Flatten[Nearest[acc -> "Index", #] & /@ stops, 1];
near = Prepend[near, 0];
dif = Differences[near];
final = TakeList[p, dif];
mcg = Row[Column[#, BaselinePosition -> Top] & /@ final, " "]
```

[image]

Comment: this is very cool! will soon try it out